# Why does my code for closing a pygame program behave differently in different programs?

Tags: pygame, exit

I made a game in snake that closes the window, but not the shell when you lose. I copy-pasted the same code into another program that allows you to do this by pressing a button (note that I'm not using the tkinter module for the button, just pygame). When I press the button, the window closes but pops back up. There is no difference in the code between the two programs, so I don't understand what's wrong.

Here's the code I used in my snake game to close the window without closing the shell:

```
if (x,y) in path:
            print("You lose. Your length was", length)
            pygame.quit()
            break
```

What's even stranger is that in my button program, the break command makes no difference regardless of if its there or not. With the snake game, I had to put that in there to stop the shell from throwing out an error message, which the button program doesn't have a problem with. I don't understand why this one function would behave differently in the two programs. There is nothing else that could be affecting it!

edit: I should note that, obviously, I remove the 'print' line which pulls a variable from my snake game. So the code in my button program is just:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        cx,cy=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if cx>(windowWidth-buttonWidth)/2 and\
               cx<(windowWidth-buttonWidth)/2+buttonWidth and\
               cy>(windowHeight-buttonHeight)/2 and\
               cy<(windowHeight-buttonHeight)/2+buttonHeight:
                    pygame.quit()
                    break
```

As for the strange variables, I used those to center my button the screen. The program is just a test I was running to figure out how to make buttons for another program I'm planning.

Comment: Typically with this sort of program there is an event-processing loop that runs "forever"  - until the window is closed, or some some of exit-condition is triggered.  When the exit is triggered, the event-loop `break`s, and then `pygame.quit()` is called.  I suspect you have an external loop around that is causing the reported behaviour.

Comment: what error message ? You skip more important information.

Answer (score 1):

`pygame.quit()` doesn't end program but only "close" pygame's modules so code is still running. If you have ie. `pygame.display.flip()`, `screen.blit()`, etc few lines later in `for`-loop  then it may still try to execute it and get error because modules are closed - values are deleted, window is closed, etc.

`break` exits `for`-loop and it may skip line which makes problem. This is why there is `quit()` which ends program.

You can also use `pygame.quit()` after exiting `mainloop` when there is no other command which uses pygame.